# Kafka Query other topics for consumed data

Tags: apache-kafka

We will have 2 topics.

Say we consume topic1 which has a message containing something like: `{id: 1, name: bob}`
and then  we wanted to check if topic2 has a message with `id:1`.

Is there a query functionality for topics to achieve this?
If no match is found, can we retrigger the search in the future to check if it has been added to the topic.

Comment: The idea behind Kafka topics is to store data in topics until it is consumed, they aren't meant for persistent storage ! So take some other choices I suggest if you want to achieve this functionality. You may consume the message and perform the check , but consumption is all ! that's it !

Comment: @Harsh you know, whole event sourcing architecture is based on storing events infinitely. See https://www.confluent.io/blog/event-sourcing-using-apache-kafka/

Answer (score 0):

There is tool exactly for this - it's [ksqldb](https://ksqldb.io/). It allows to work with different topics like with database tables and also allows to correlate events when they happen and [match query](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/join-streams-and-tables/).

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to consume both topics.

Topic1 can be consumed into a KTable, then Topic2 would do lookups against its statestore.

https://kafka.apache.org/32/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_concepts_duality

"Query functionality" is called "interactive queries" in the documentation.

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, you can dump the data records into some external database (e.g. Using Kafka Connect or Apache Camel) with index lookup support, then simply have your consumer query that database.